# SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster installation, can I install on the 2 nodes at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failovercluster

I've configured the Windows cluster, now I need to install SQL Server on the 2 nodes. To save time, I want to know if I can install on the 2 nodes at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: No you cannot. The installation requires you to have an existing node first, before adding the second. On appropriate hardware, you're hardly saving any time.

Comment: the trick is that the second node is taking the config from the first node. So during install second (and more nodes) they need to access first node to get their configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL 2005 you can do this but since 2008 you have to run setup for every node in your cluster.